# Changing a button's text color when tapped

Tags: swift, uibutton

I'm trying to get a button's text to change font color to red when tapped. I looked at similar posts from months ago and use of that code causes a build error in Xcode 6.1.1.  Here is the code I'm trying:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func firstButton(sender: UIButton) { 
        firstButton.titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }
}
```

The error code that I get is:

> '(UIButton) -> ()' does not have a member named 'titleLabel'

Any help will be much appreciated as I see Swift as my saving grace after having lost patience in trying to learn Objective C.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're trying to change the text color of the function's `titleLabel`, which doesn't make sense. You should be accessing `sender` parameter instead if you're trying to get a reference to the button to get at its `titleLabel`. Additionally, as rakeshbs points out, `titleLabel` is an optional property of UIButton.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func firstButton(sender: UIButton) {
        sender.titleLabel?.textColor  = UIColor.redColor()
    }
}
```

If you break down your error message, you'll realize that this is clearly the issue.

> '(UIButton) -> ()' does not have a member named 'titleLabel'

Which states that you are trying to access a member (or property) named `titleLabel` on an object of type `(UIButton) -> ()`, which means a function that takes a button as input and returns nothing.

Comment: That was the problem.  I wasn't accessing the sender, I was trying to access the button through its name.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 14):

For anyone interested in the exact swift code necessary to make this question of mine work, here it is:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBAction func firstButton(sender: UIButton) {

    sender.setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

}
```

Answer (score 5):

this will work for **Swift 3 :**

> yourButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: .normal)

Answer (score 2):

`UIButton.titlelabel` is an optional property. You have to use optional chaining for changing its properties.

```
firstButton.titleLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

Please read about swift optionals to understand this in detail.
http://www.appcoda.com/beginners-guide-optionals-swift/